# How to get text() of Child Component in Enzyme / React

Tags: reactjs, testing, text, enzyme

I've got a `childComponent` that has text.

I've written a `test` that is checking for that text. That test passed until **I made two notable changes.** I need to keep those changes, and get the test to pass.

1. The component has been refactored to use `forwardRef`
2. The childComponent I'm trying to test for text is defined as a property of the parentComponent e.g. `parentComponent.childComponent = childComponent`

The test works fine when the parentComponent does not use `forwardRef`

I can see the text in the `childComponent` when I print the html() of the parent in the console.

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="parentComponent">
    <div class="childComponent">
      childText
    </div>
  </div>
```

**parentComponent:**

```
class SelectRef extends PureComponent {
   /// component code here
} 
// Bottom of parentComponent
const Select = forwardRef((props, ref) => <SelectRef {...props} innerRef={ref} />);
Select.displayName = "Select";
Select.Option = Option;

export default Select;
```

**I've tried:**

```
expect(component.dive().text()).to.contain("text");
expect(component.shallow().text()).to.contain("text");
expect(component.prop('children')).to.contain("text");
```

**What are other ways to get the childComponent text in a component using Enyzme / React?**

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do this when using **forwardRef**:

I have a **helper** function in the enzyme test that allows you to access the **class** function in the **forwardRef** wrapper:

```
const getComp = (comp, className = "default-class") =>
  comp
    .find("ComponentRef")
    .dive()
    .find(className);
```

**Example test:**

```
  it("should render the place holder text", () => {
      const component = shallow(
        <Component placeholderText="Select an option" selectName="test"/>
      );

      const comp = getComp(component)
      expect(comp.text()).to.contain("inner text of component");
  });
```